# Unable to start/launch local mongo db

Tags: mongodb, localhost, local

I'm new to MongoDB. I currently have a dump of a mongo db (i.e. directory of .bson files) and am trying to import that into mongo.

I installed mongo as per the instructions on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/.

I'm currently trying to test starting a local mongo instance by running mongod --dbpath /path/to/my/mongodata (which is an empty directory).

I get the following in stdout:

```
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1065 port=27017 dbpath=/path/to/my/mongodata/ 64-bit host=dhcp-18-111-28-92.dyn.mit.edu
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] 
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 266 processes, 2560 files. Number of processes should be at least 1280 : 0.5 times number of files.
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.0, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] git version: f5e83eae9cfbec7fb7a071321928f00d1b0c5207
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-1.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/path/to/my/mongodata/" }
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] journal dir=/path/to/my/mongodata/journal
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Thu Sep 20 09:46:01 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

At this point, it just hangs there and does nothing. Seems like it's waiting for something to happen on localhost, but I don't know mongo well enough to understand what's going on. Any help?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37548118/2404470) can help

Answer (score 158, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, you have started the server, it is running and listening on port `27017`. Now you can start to interact with the server, for example just open a new terminal tab and run `mongo` ,which will open mongo's interactive console and connects to the default server(`localhost:27017`)

If you want to run mongod as a background process (to get back the console) you can use [--fork](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo#StartingandStoppingMongo-RunningasaDaemon) command option. This requires you to use some sort of [logging.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Logging)

Eg. `mongod --dbpath /path/to/my/mongodata --fork --logpath /path/to/my/mongod.log`

If you want to restore a bsonexport you will probably use the [mongorestore](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongorestore) command

Comment: Mattias is correct, and here is a full official docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: I see the exact same message on my terminal, "NETWORK waiting for connections on 27017". But if I open a new terminal tab and run "mongo", it says command not found. Not sure if there is any error that is causing it to not run?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below in the configuration file and call  it using `monogd`, make sure your `bind_ip` is configured as per your requirement and use the below link to add few more replica sets:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

**Step 1:**

```
vi /etc/mongod.conf

replication: replSetName: rs01
```

**Step 2:**

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

**Output:**

```
warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 30012
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below 2 steps:

**Step 1:**
Open CMD and enter `mongod`. This will run the mongo server

**Step 2:**
Open another Command Prompt, move to the location of file and type

```
mongorestore -d db_name -c collection_name file.bson
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from official documentation

> This starts the main MongoDB database process. The waiting for
>   connections message in the console output indicates that the
>   mongod.exe process is running successfully.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Answer (score -1):

pressing ctrl+c or ctrl+z will stop mongod service,and just run sudo servie mongod start