# Mongodb windows setup "admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017" error

Tags: windows, mongodb

I have a problem on mongodb setup.
I am using windows 8 64 bit, downloaded package for windows.

While I am trying to install this package on cmd, I get an error.

http://prntscr.com/1ct7pa

It's stoped this line "[websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017"

How can I repair this error?

thanks.

edit:
I realized from answers, "this problem isn't error".

I try this command, it worked flawlessly.

```
mongod --logpath c:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db --directoryperdb --install
```

Comment: its not an error, the two line, including the one in question means it is running perfectly fine and is waiting for connections

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot start local mongo db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514119/cannot-start-local-mongo-db)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the attached screenshot, MongoDB server has started successfully. By running mongod.exe you have started MongoDB server. It is now ready to accept connections from MongoDB clients. You can connect to your MongoDB server using MongoDB shell, a MongoDB client, or your application, and perform database operations. To start the MongoDB shell, use the following from command prompt.

[image]

By default, MongoDB server listens on port 27017. In addition, the MongoDB admin console listens on MongoDB port number + 1000. Here you are using port 27017 for your MongoDB, hence admin console is on port 28017. The following url will take you to the admin console.

```
http://kubilay:28017/
```

Answer (score 1):

I try this command, it worked flawlessly.

```
mongod --logpath c:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db --directoryperdb --install
```

And windows service Mongodb started successful.

I like that ;)