# How do I start Mongo DB from Windows?

Tags: mongodb, connection, windows-7-x64

I have installed MongoDB on my Windows 7 (64 bit) machine. I have created the path data/db too but when I tried to start mongodb using the command `'C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe'`, it is not starting. It is showing `admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017`.

Help me in starting the MongoDB. And also please suggest if any GUI is available for MongoDB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot start local mongo db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514119/cannot-start-local-mongo-db)

Comment: For mongo client just check this one http://robomongo.org/

Comment: Windows installation need to be completed and then configured before starting. watch this for steps - Mongo 3 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msQ2F5XUgms

Comment: This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/31132332/73323

Answer (score 361):

## Step 1

Download the [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community)

## Step 2

- Follow *normal* setup instructions

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Step 3

- Create the following folder

`C:\data\db`

## Step 4

- `cd` to `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>`
- enter command `mongod`
- by default, mongodb server will start at port `27017`

[image]

## Step 5

- (optionally) download [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/download) and follow *normal* setup instructions

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Step 6

- Start RoboMongo and create a new connection on `localhost:27017`

[image]

Your MongoDB is started and connected with RoboMongo (now Robo 3T) - a third party GUI tool

Comment: @mok can you [update the answer with Robo 3T](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37548118/edit)?

Comment: My issue was I did not have c:\data\db folder in the path... But, I was able to run Mongodb v4 and v5 successfully and got this issue only after migrating to v6.

Answer (score 121):

This worked for me

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\MongoDB\data\db
```

Comment: Be sure that the path to the mongod.exe binary has to the $path variable or that you are in the directory with the mongod executable.

Comment: but I need to do this every time is there any other way to do this by simple `mongod` command

Comment: I needed a second service running to migrate, this was what I needed. While in /MongoDB/Server/4.2/bin, I used `mongod.exe --port 27018 --dbpath ../data`. Thanks

Answer (score 69):

1. Download from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads
2. Install **.msi** file in folder **C:\mongodb**
3. Create **data**, **data\db**, **log** directories and **mongo.config** file under **C:\mongodb**.
4. Add the following lines in "**mongo.config**" file

   ```
   port=27017
   dbpath=C:\mongodb\data\db\
   logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log
   ```
5. Start server :

   ```
   mongod.exe --config="C:\mongodb\mongo.config"
   ```
6. Connect to localhost MongoDB server via command line

   ```
   mongo --port 27017
   ```
7. Connect to remote MongoDB server via command line with authentication.

   ```
   mongo --username abcd --password abc123 --host server_ip_or_dns --port 27017
   ```

That's it !!!

Comment: may is not best solution, but is clean way.

Comment: just tried this, for the latest mongo 4.2 version, here are the changes: 
1) mongod.config -> now called mongod.cfg located in the mongo server bin folder. 2) "port" is under "net" -> net.port 3) dbpath -> storage.dbPath (upper case P in path). 4) logpath -> systemLog.path

Answer (score 47):

Create MongoDB Service in Windows. First Open cmd with administrator

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "a mongodb storage actual path e.g: d:\mongo_storage\data" --logpath="a log path e.g: d:\mongo_storage\log\log.txt" --install --serviceName "MongoDB"
```

After that

Start Service

```
net start MongoDB
```

Stop Service

```
net stop MongoDB
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks for the answer. Greatly Appreciated!

Answer (score 26):

Step 1:
First download the .msi i.e is the installation file from

https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production

Step 2:
Perform the installation using the so downloaded .msi file.Automatically it gets stored in program files.
You could perform a custom installation and change the directory.

After this you should be able to see a Mongodb folder

Step 3:
Create a new folder in this Mongodb folder with name 'data'. Create another new folder in your data directory with the name 'db'.

Step 4:
Open cmd. Go to the directory where your mongodb folder exists and go to a path like C:\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin.
In the bin folder you should have mongodb.exe

Step 5:
Now use

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "C:\MongoDB\data\db"
```

Comment: it does not work for me without equal sign, hence: "C:\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod --dbpath=C:\data\db" from source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404742/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows

Comment: Ohh... i think i forgot the quotes in my answer..updated now.

Answer (score 19):

there are 2 ways start mongoDB
Install location ( ex : C:/ )

first of all : copy mongoDB install folder into C:/ location
then changed name to "mongodb" or something what u want. here is ex with "mongodb" name

1 : setup mongoDB is an windows service

```
    1.1 : Make directory name "data" in C:/ ( so we have C:/data ),after that make directory "C:/data/db" <br>
    1.2 : run in CMD ( Run as Admin) command ->  "echo logpath=C:/mongodb/log/mongo.log > C:/mongodb/mongodb.cfg" <br>
    1.3 : run in CMD (Run as Adin) command -> "C:/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe --config C:/mongodb/mongod.cfg --install" <br>
    1.4 : run command "net start MongoDB" <br>
```

2: a small .BAT file to start mongoDB without install
   copy and paste to notepad and save file with filetype ".bat"
   here is it :

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe –dbpath=C:/mongodb/data/db
   PAUSE
```

if you getting error 1078 or 1087
lets remove all data in C:/data/db and restart mongoDB ( copy old data to new folder and back it up after restart mongoDB )

3 . GUI for mongoDB

i'm using [rockmongo](http://rockmongo.com)

have fun with it

Comment: the correct option is: "--dbpath=C:/mongodb/data/db" 
(double dash)

Answer (score 19):

I did below, it works for me in windows.

open cmd prompt in Administrator mode( right click command prompt and click "run as administrator")

then run below command

```
net start MongoDB
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I don't have to know the params it's set up with --

Answer (score 13):

I have followed the below steps...May be it will work for you

Create directory like below

**C:\DATA\DB**

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "C:\data\db"
```

It worked for me....

Answer (score 8):

It is properly written over [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

If you download the .msi file then install it and if you download the zip file then extract it.

> Set up the MongoDB environment.

MongoDB requires a **data directory to store all data**. MongoDB’s default data directory path is **\data\db**. **Create this folder** using the following commands from a Command Prompt:

`md \data\db`

You can specify an alternate path for data files using the --dbpath option to mongod.exe, for example:

`C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data`

If your path includes spaces, enclose the entire path in double quotes, for example:

`C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath "d:\test\mongo db data"`

You may also specify the dbpath in a configuration file.

> Start MongoDB.

To start MongoDB, run mongod.exe. For example, from the Command Prompt:

`C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe`

> Connect to MongoDB.

To connect to MongoDB through the mongo.exe shell, open another Command Prompt.

`C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe`

Answer (score 7):

Installing MongoDB on Windows is a bit tricky compared to other Executable files... Got a good reference after long search I got [Installing MongoDB in Windows](http://www.codeverb.com/get-started-with-mongodb-on-windows)

After Installing open command prompt and type "mongod", then keep the window minimized and open another command prompt window and type "mongo" and you will find the success message of connecting to the test database.

hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

`It is showing admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017.`

The above message means that mongodb has started successfully and is listening on port 28017.

You can use the mongo shell(`mongo.exe`) to connect to the mongoDB and perform db operations.

There are several GUI tools available for MongoDB like MongoVUE, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Actually windows way to use service, from the official [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition):

- Find out where is your executable is installed, path may be like this:

  "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe"
- Create config file with such content (yaml format), path may be like this:

  "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\mongod.cfg"

```yaml
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
```

- Execute as admin the next command (run command line as admin):

```sh
C:\...\mongod.exe --config C:\...\mongod.cfg --install
```

Where paths is reduced with dots, see above.

The key `--install` say to mongo to install itself as windows service.

Now you can start, stop, restart mongo server as usual windows service choose your favorite way from this:

- from `Control Panel` -> `Administration` -> `Services` -> `MongoDB`
- by command execution from command line as admin: (`net start MongoDB`)

Check log file specified in config file if any problems.

Comment: how to set `directoryperdb` option

Answer (score 5):

Download MongoDB Community Server from the link - https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community

The installation takes some time. Once done, follow these steps to get your server running-

1. Go to C drive, make a folder named data and inside that create another folder named db.
2. Now move to directory where monodb server is installed. Go to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server(Version)\bin. Copy this file location.
3. To make it easier to run server in future, press windows key and type environment variables.
4. You will see an option 'Edit the system environment variables'.
5. On the lower right corner, you will see a button 'Environment Variables...'. Click that.
6. Under System variables, double click on path.
7. Click on new and paste the file location you copied earlier.
8. Now open cmd, and type mongod.exe (It's a daemon which hosts the server.)
9. Open another window of cmd and type mongo.exe The connection will be established and you are good to go now.

Thanks for reading. Hope it helps.

Comment: you can type `mongo` instead of `mongo.exe` and `mongod` instead of `mongod.exe`

Answer (score 4):

**This is ALL** I needed to init mongo in PowerShell, many replies are IMO too sophisticated.

1. Install: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community
2. Add `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin` to environmental
   variable "path". Notice: this version will be outdated soon.
3. Turn on new PowerShell, as it gets environmental variables on a
   start, then type *mongod*
4. Open another PowerShell window and type *mongo* - you have access to mongo REPL! If you don't, just repeat 4 again (known bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32473)

Answer (score 3):

Clearly many people have answered upon your query of how to make mongoDb work,
I'd answer the second part: Regarding an appropriate GUI for mongoDB

My suggestion is, go for **MongoChef (now Studio 3T)**

You can easily install and use it.

You might want want to refer to (from 03:10- to 08:50): 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ws3oIyqieY&index=2&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZtR6bncmSaH8fB81oRl6MP

For a step by step guide to the GUI tool.

Comment: It just claims to be comment quality

Comment: i suggest the normal version, not the Studio version of 3T

Answer (score 3):

an additional thing you can do that is amazing

is that you can add "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin" to your system environment variables , this will allow you to RUN the command "mongod" in any place in your cmd without navigating to the bin directory every time.

-- note the the path to the bin directory can be different in your case --

so to arrange things up

1- make a folder data/db in your c drive "this is the default path mongo will look for the place to store your database files , so you do not have to specify it using '--dbpath' "

2- add "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin" to your system environment variables.

3- open CMD type 'mongod'

4- have fun

--  i saw this on a youtube channel called 'thenewboston' ,
which is also amazing --

Comment: This does not really answer the question being asked, rather explains an alternative way to start the program.

Comment: i suppose he has installed mongoDB , rather than that i specified after

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users:

To add onto @CoderSpeed's answer above ([CoderSpeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20799312/5925104)).
Create a batch file (.bat) with the commands you would usually enter on the CLI, e.g.:

`cd "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin"
 mongod.exe`

Windows Script Host’s Run Method allows you run a program or script in invisible mode. Here is a sample Windows script code that launches a batch file named syncfiles.bat invisibly.

Let’s say we have a file named syncfiles.bat in C:\Batch Files directory. Let’s launch it in hidden mode using Windows Scripting.

Copy the following lines to Notepad.

`Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
 WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Batch Files\syncfiles.bat" & Chr(34), 0
 Set WshShell = Nothing`

Note: Replace the batch file name/path accordingly in the script according to your requirement.
Save the file with .VBS extension, say launch_bat.vbs
Edit the .BAT file name and path accordingly, and save the file.
Double-click to run the launch_bat.vbs file, which in-turn launches the batch file syncfiles.bat invisibly.

Sourced from:
[Run .BAT files invisibly](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/)

Answer (score 2):

I have installed MongoDB in `D:\Installs` folder instead of default location.

Open command prompt and change directory into `D:\Installs\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin` and run the following command:

`mongod.exe --config=mongod.cfg`

This should start the MongoDB service.

Now, Open MongoDB Compass and connect as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If from all these ways if your database not working you can try this

First, install Monngodb from the official site

second, go to this path

```
  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin
```

Third run server using **mongod** command

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart your cmd
2. Type `mongo` OR `mongod` in your cmd and press enter.

That's it :)

Answer (score -2):

You can start Mongo also as a Win Service!

Start
Stop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How? How do you Start/ Stop it?