# Mongodb: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061

Tags: windows, mongodb, database, nosql

Here is my `mongod.cfg` file:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
dbpath = C:\mongodb\data\db
logpath = C:\mongodb\log\mongo-server.log
verbose=v
```

Here is my `mongod` service command:

```
mongod -f c:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --install
```

I have installed MongoDB about a week ago and it all worked fine, however today when I ran `mongo` command I got the following error:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017,
reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

**How can I fix that?** *I use Windows 8.1*

**Solution:**

I forgot to start mongodb service with this command:

```
net start mongodb
```

**Improved solution:**

**1)** Change directory to root drive `C:\`, and type the command below into an admin `cmd` prompt window,

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --config c:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --install
```

**2)** Then type `net start MongoDB` after which you should see the following message:

```
"The Mongo DB service was started successfully"
```

**3)** Then go to the control panel `Start>Administrative Tools>Services`, scroll down to MongoDB in the list of services and change start up type to automatic, if you so desire. Press OK.

**4)** Finally type `C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe` and you should be connected to the Mongo test DB.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mik4dPArCU

Comment: Check if mongod is running.

Comment: Warn: if it pretty silently fails (well: visible in log only), you forgot to use an admin prompt...

Comment: Update: As of mongoDB 2.6 and greater, [YAML syntax for the `.cfg`is recommended](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/).

Comment: @vmr I admit, this is the problem I was having...

Comment: @FrankN thanks for that, it (eventually) saved me a lot of headache

Comment: @mikeTheLiar i can't find the file `mongod.cfg`

Answer (score 171, accepted):

This is how I solved it, You can follow step by step here:

MongoDB Steps:

- Download the latest 64-bit MSI version of [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads) for Windows.
- Run the installer (.msi file)
- Add it to your **PATH** of environment variables. it Should be from:
  `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin`

now Create a “\data\db” folder in **C:/** which is used by *mongodb* to store all data. You should have this folder:

C:\data\db

> Note: This is the default directory location expected by mongoDB,
>   don’t create anywhere else

.

Finally, open command prompt and type:

```
>> mongod
```

You should see it asking for permissions (allow it) and then listen to a port. 
After that is done, open another command prompt, leaving the previous one running the server.

Type in the new command prompt

```
>> mongo
```

You should see it display the  version and connect to a test database.

This proves successful install!=)

[Reference link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_5mj3-_uJQ)

Comment: hey this a tutorial for mongo installation :o! I have the error described on this question, but reinstall i don´t think would be a good solution.

Comment: It was a solution that worked for me. By re-installing.

Comment: This helped me as well, especially that note about the directory location. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

When you typed in the mongod command, did you also give it a path? This is usually the issue. You don't have to bother with the conf file. simply type

mongod --dbpath="put your path to where you want it to save the working area for your database here!! without these silly quotations marks I may also add!"

example: mongod --dbpath=C:/Users/kyles2/Desktop/DEV/mongodb/data

That is my path and don't forget if on windows to flip the slashes forward if you copied it from the or it won't work!

Comment: This is what worked for me. Specifically, i ran `mongod --dbpath=C:\data\db`. You might notice that the `C:\data\db` is the default folder for the data storage mentioned in @morecast answer and @Chee Loong Soon answer

Comment: worked for me ( mongod --dbpath=C:\data\db ) then inanother cmd run mongo command

Comment: worked for me as well after trying for an hour

Answer (score 8):

I was also faced the same issue with mongodb 2.6.

What solved my problem was I just run **`mongod --repair`** command

and then start `mongod.exe`

It's worked for me

Answer (score 6):

just create a folder

```
C:\data\db
```

Run below commands in command prompt

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongod
```

Open another command prompt

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongo
```

Answer (score 4):

mongodb 2.6.8 on windows7 32bits
you only need create a folder c:/data/db
execute mongod, and execute mongo

Answer (score 3):

Point to your mongodb instalation e.g C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Serve\bin and run mongod.exe so you can open connection to 127.0.0.1:27017.

Answer (score 2):

If it writes that you had not properly shut down or that mongod.lock is not empty
, only delete mongod.lock from C:\data\db\ and it will start.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal conditions, at least 3379 MB of disk space is needed. If you do not have that much space, to lower this requirement;

```
mongod.exe --smallfiles
```

This is not the only requirement. But this may be your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that I missed out 'db' folder for the dbpath in the command:

```
C:\mongodb\bin> mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongodb.log --logappend -rest --install
```

Comment: This worked for me! I had to give it a `--dbpath` to mongod command and then ran `mongo` in a different shell and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

What solved my issue was creating a file startmongo.conf that sets the bind_ip to 127.0.0.1 . After that, I just created a *.bat to start the mongo using something like:

```
mongod --config c:\mongodb\bin\startmongo.conf
```

Comment: I wonder this is exactly the same as [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23841649/1179841).

Comment: well, not *exactly* the same. This one is way newer. And it doesn't give credit to (both) of the sources of information.
;)

Comment: No need for a batch btw, since (as of Jan '16, Version 3.2) the mongodb service is set to automatic (startup after boot). If you wanted to change that `sc config "mongodb" start= demand`

Answer (score 0):

When This Error is Coming it is  lack of the following

1)Setting the path to mongo db 
go to "C" Drive and the installation of Mongo db directory and then go to bin folder in the mongo and copy the path of it

> c:/mongodb/server/3.2/bin/ and create a new environmental variable in system properties then name is path and value="c:/mongodb/server/3.2/bin/" here my version is 3.2

2)create a data directory for the data in C Drive
c:/Data/twitter

3)start the server with **

> c:/> mongod

check your port config if there is any error as the local port may be assigned to any other
4)start your Mongo database with

> Mongo
>   then your mongo db will start

then in your mongo database 
**create a database**

> use DATABASE_NAME

for example:

use twitterdata

switched to db twitterdata

to check your current database

> db

twitterdata

to get total databases

> show dbs

Answer (score 0):

I started mongod in cmd,It threw error like C:\data\db\ not found.
Created folder then typed mongod
opened another cmd typed mongo it worked.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to solve this issue:

1. Just go to your MongoDB bin folder and run the mongod.exe file.
2. Navigate to your mongodb bin folder via Command prompt and start mongo by typing "mongo"

Answer (score 0):

Change file permission to 755 for the file:

```
/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

first you run the command mongod and check weather the port 27017 has started or not if yes then hit the command mongo....and database will start.

Answer (score -1):

The Port is  not open. Thats why the machine refuses communication

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
mongod --storageEngine=mmpav1
```