# MongoDB get error as an the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mongodb, nosql

i'm newbie in mongodb and after installing mongo installer package on windows i get this error when i try to use mongo on shell and command prompt. i can not find any solution for this problem:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: test
2015-02-20T16:43:11.971+0330 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reas
on: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2015-02-20T16:43:11.987+0330 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (
127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed

C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure that `mongod` is up and running.

Another probable cause would be that the port is not open.

I've come across the following thread on SO with multiple possible solutions to your problem --- [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585433/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-127017-reason-errno10061)