# Mongodb error in localhost windows

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, database

i have downloaded mongodb msi file form mongodb website and i have installed successfully in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
And i used command as mongodb on a command prompt with administrator privileges 
but error occurred as

> 

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: test
2016-01-05T15:08:52.215+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2016-01-05T15:08:52.229+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:224:14
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

image of cmd prompt is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We0Yz.png)

after executing mongod command error is like

> 

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod
2016-01-05T15:06:15.150+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12512 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-3F1GEI5
2016-01-05T15:06:15.161+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008
2016-01-05T15:06:15.167+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.0
2016-01-05T15:06:15.171+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 45d947729a0315accb6d4f15a6b06be6d9c19fe7
2016-01-05T15:06:15.179+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-01-05T15:06:15.183+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-01-05T15:06:15.186+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-01-05T15:06:15.190+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-01-05T15:06:15.195+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-01-05T15:06:15.200+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-01-05T15:06:15.238+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2016-01-05T15:06:15.246+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Comment: you need to start `mongod` first then connect to it with `mongo`

Comment: first of start mongodb server using mongod command and then open new command prompt and run mongo

Comment: i have tried it already but it is not working.

Comment: do you have log ? does `mongod` start successful or it fail ? Your error looked like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585433/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-127017-reason-errno10061

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mongod direct command contain some by default parameter

```
mongod --dbpath=C:\data\db\   --port=27017
```

so create a folder data in c then create a db folder in that then run the command

```
mongod
```

your server will be in running state now connect to it using

```
mongo --port=27017
```

this will work for you if problem then comment