# MongoDB does not start

Tags: mongodb

I am learning MongoDB and when I am trying to start mongoDb, it throws me the error below:

```
C:\Users\Mahadev>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3
connecting to: test
2016-02-18T14:45:06.028+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1
:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machi
ne actively refused it.
2016-02-18T14:45:06.029+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to ser
ver 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:224:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

How do I solve the error?

Comment: Start server first. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

What solved my issue was creating a file `startmongo.conf` that sets the `bind_ip`to `127.0.0.1` . After that, I just created a `*.bat` to start the mongo using something like:

```
mongod --config c:\mongodb\bin\startmongo.conf
```

Reference : [Mongodb: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585433/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-127017-reason-errno10061)

Answer (score 0):

May this work

```
sudo mongod --repair
sudo mongod
```

(forget about service and start)

Then on a different tab/terminal:

```
mongo
```