# Unable to resolve error with steps to connect mongodb with nodejs on WebStorm

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

As I have installed mongodb package using:

```
npm install mongodb --save
```

on terminal and made a file connection.js. Code inside it is:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_database_name';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established to', url);
        db.close();
    }
});
```

And running command:

```
C:\Users\upasana\Desktop\node>node connection.js
```

on terminal. The error that I am facing is:

> Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error: { [MongoError:connection 0 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out]
>   name: 'MongoError',
>   message: 'connection 0 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out' }

Comment: Is mongo running? I suspect it is not

Comment: Are you running a local MongoDB on your machine?

Comment: yes,i installed the mongodb package ,locally

Comment: Please,suggest me how to correct the error.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests you're not running MongoDB on the server and are subsequently receiving a timeout as no connection can be established..

Check to make sure the MondoDB server is running by using a `netstat -ano | grep mongo' and check if its running.

Just incase, try restarting it using `sudo service mongodb restart`.

Attempt to run the `connection.js` file again. If its still getting the same error, let me know.

Comment: Sir,I have a confusion,i am newbie to this technology and watched a lot many videos,and got 2 ways to connect to mongodb first was installing mongodb and working on cmd and second was i am using webstrom and working on nodejs and want to connect database to it,i have tried to explain all the steps,hope u won't mind explaining in the direction i want to know,sry for the reply besides the topic but if u can help in step by step to the solution of the problem..

Comment: @upasanaarora Oh sorry, you're using Windows? In which case, go to your Windows `services` and make sure that Mongodb is running in your services list. If you want to ensure its started successfully, try following suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796714/what-is-the-way-to-start-mongo-db-from-windows-7-64-bit

To summarise, your MongoDB instance isn't running.

Comment: Sir,the link u have provided i have tried that way nd that is working but i was trying to do it using webstrom software installing package using npm install mongodb --save command and then adding connection that way it is not working...,i have explained that in my Question....If u can help in that direction.