# Can't connect to MongoDB server (no error and no messages in the console)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, database

I installed MongoDB on Windows, made a data folder in C: directory and made a db folder inside that data folder, but mongod.exe doesn't want to run. The weirdest thing is that it doesn't give me an error or any message, it just skips to the next line like nothing happened.

Here is a screenshot of the console:

[image: Screenshot of the console]

Also when I try to connect the route of mongo.exe to the PhpStorm's Mongo Plugin, PhpStorm doesn't recognize 
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongo.exe" as the path to Mongo Shell.

I installed MongoDB the same way on my other computer that uses Windows 10 and it worked, but on this one that uses Windows 7 it doesn't work.

Comment: have you open admin cmd ?

Comment: how about trying mongo -v or something to see if the mongodb is properly installed

Comment: @krishnpatel Tried opening up as administrator and the situation is still the same.

Comment: @sacDahal Tried entering mongo -v into the cmd, and nothing happened, so it probably isn't properly installed. I'll try to repair it or reinstall it.

Comment: **mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\data\db**        try this

Comment: if you don't get refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796714/how-do-i-start-mongo-db-from-windows

Comment: @krishnpatel Uninstalled MongoDB, and installed it following those steps from the link that you sent me, but it still doesnt want to start. I also typed mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\data\db and still nothing.

Comment: see also other ans there in the link. it may be work. see and try you will get the success

Comment: @krishnpatel Nothing seems to work, I'm quite confused, don't know what the problem is, it worked great on my other computer. I'm guessing that the windows firewall or some windows feature is blocking the access, I doubt that I didn't install it correctly.