# Windows 10: How to fix 'Service MongoDB server' (MongoDB) failed to start as service after installing MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I tried to install MongoDB on my machine and after the installation is about to finish it is throwing an error stating "Service MongoDB server' (MongoDB) failed to star".

[image: MongoDB error]

And while I try to run `mongod.exe` it's getting failed.

Please help me with this. Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478113/unable-to-start-mongodb-local-server?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796714/how-do-i-start-mongo-db-from-windows?rq=1 answers in this questions will be also relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem.

[image: msi installation error]

Install complete version to default folders will help, because it writes default path address for MongoDB Server service, check it by running Win+R

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with Administrator.

Comment: Tried. Still same problem is persisting.

Comment: 1. Navigate to Group Policy Object Editor > Local Computer Policy.
2. In the console tree, navigate to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies >User Rights Assignment.
3. In the details pane, double-click Log on as a service.
4. Click Add User or Group and add the account to the list of accounts that have the Log on as a service right.