# How to fix: Can not connect to the databaseMongoNetworkError

Tags: angular, mongodb

I'm buildind a program under angular7 and i'm trying to use a remote mongodb database.

In my DB.js file in the angular project, which is the file where i specify the database i want to write in, i'm using this code:

```
 DB: 'mongodb://192.168.1.249:27017/test'
```

Where 'ip address' represent the ip address of the server where my database is located. And 'test' is the name of the database.

When i start the nodemon server in order to access to mongodb after i'm having this error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-mac:api mac$ nodemon server
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Listening on port 4000
Can not connect to the databaseMongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.249:27017
```

Comment: have you started your local mongo db server?

Comment: how to start local mongo db server?

Comment: @Chirag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796714/how-do-i-start-mongo-db-from-windows

Comment: @GopeshSharma yes, i started my local mongo db server. I run itno this error when i'm calling the command "nodemon"

Comment: The problem is that it is not finding anything running on 27017 on that IP check your IP adress of the server and that the port is really open

Comment: @JuanesVelasquez it's all good. The ip is correct and the the port is opened and it's listening. But still facing that issue