# How to host MEAN stack application with Angular and nodejs on windows IIS

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have angular at frontend with node at backend and I need to run both on a windows server. The Angular I am able to host using URL rewrite in IIS but am confused about what to do with nodejs code?
Am I supposed to start nodejs code via cmd and then Angular on IIS?
Also how should i keep the mongod.exe started while i host? I want to know how to host everything on production server.

Answer (score 1):

Your Angular approach is okay. If rewrite works, be happy.

For **NodeJS** project, if you launch `npm run start` (or whatever script you use), Windows' CMD (or PowerShell), at least on Windows Server, when you logout from your session usually blocks/freezes the console, so you literally got nothing.

Now, to solve it, **PM2** tool is your friend ( https://pm2.keymetrics.io/ ). Follow their docs, it's super easy to configure and run.

I'm not an user of **mongo**. I'd say you'll need a service to keep it always running.

(***edit***) I found this question here: [How do I start Mongo DB from Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796714/how-do-i-start-mongo-db-from-windows)